# What is the purpose of cachedConstructor field in java.lang.Class?

Tags: java, class, classloader

Is it used by classloader? Can you recommend any specific articles or documentation to read about peculiarities of java.lang.Class and classloaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont find much in the way of documentation for this because it is a field private to the inner workings of the `java.lang.Class` and may or may not exist depending on the implementation of the JDK you are looking at.

If you have a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Class.java#Class.newInstance%28%29) for OpenJDK at the `newInstance()` method I think it is quite obviously what is it doing. It is caching the reference to the default constructor so that repetitive calls to `newInstance()` don't have to find it each time.

A simple Google search found a brief [article](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html) about the internals of the ClassLoader.